# How to transfer files to different sub folders based on file name

Tags: powershell

I have these files for daily recording of my CCTV, these are default output based on a date every day. I just want a script to transfer them into NAS storage with their specific channel folder.

```
01_20190515_135255
02_20190515_135315
03_20190515_135317
04_20190515_135317
```

I need a script to move them to their specific folders  based on their channel

```
N:\Rover\CH1
N:\Rover\CH2
N:\Rover\CH3
N:\Rover\CH4
```

In other words, I want just to organize them into their respective folder into my NAS storage. I have my script below this working for basic transferring. I think I just need a little addition to my request to organize them into NAS storage.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "default path" -Recurse |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-date).AddDays(-31)} |
Move-Item -destination "destination"
```

I have searched a lot on the web and I  figure it out that script will be using regex for this kind of process. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "default path" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-31) }

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $channel     = ($file.BaseName -replace '^([0-9]+)_.*','$1').TrimStart("0")
    $destination = "N:\Rover\CH$channel"
    $file | Move-Item -destination $destination
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$DestinationPath = 'N:\Rover'

Get-ChildItem -Path "MyPath" -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-date).AddDays(-31)} | ForEach-Object {
    $Channel = ('CH' + $_.BaseName.Split("_")[0].TrimStart('0'))
    $DestinationFolder = Join-Path -Path $DestinationPath -ChildPath $Channel
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationFolder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation of a theme.

- as Move-Item accepts piped input
- use RegEx based `-match` operator with a (capture group) to store the first two digits in the automatic variable `$Matches[1]`,
- build the `-Destination` in a `{script block}` using the -f format operator.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\23\SO_56270164.ps1
$Source = "A:\Test"  # "X:\What\ever"
$Target = "A:\Rover" # "N:\Rover"
$DaysOld = (Get-date).Date.AddDays(-31)

Get-ChildItem -Path "$Source\[0-9][0-9]_*_*" -File -Recurse |
  Where-Object {($_.LastWritetime -lt $DaysOld) -and
                ($_.BaseName -match '^(\d{2})_\d{8}_\d{6}') } |
    Move-Item -Destination {'{0}\CH{1}' -f $Target,([int]$Matches[1]) } -WhatIf
# Remove -WhatIf if the output looks OK
```

Sample run:

```
> gci A:\Test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019-04-15     00:00              0 01_20190415_135255.ext
-a----       2019-05-15     00:00              0 01_20190515_135255.ext
-a----       2019-04-15     00:00              0 02_20190415_135315.ext
-a----       2019-05-15     00:00              0 02_20190515_135315.ext
-a----       2019-04-15     00:00              0 03_20190415_135317.ext
-a----       2019-05-15     00:00              0 03_20190515_135317.ext
-a----       2019-04-15     00:00              0 04_20190415_135317.ext
-a----       2019-05-15     00:00              0 04_20190515_135317.ext

> Q:\Test\2019\05\23\SO_56270164.ps1
> tree A:\ /F
A:\
├───Rover
│   ├───CH1
│   │       01_20190415_135255.ext
│   │
│   ├───CH2
│   │       02_20190415_135315.ext
│   │
│   ├───CH3
│   │       03_20190415_135317.ext
│   │
│   └───CH4
│           04_20190415_135317.ext
│
└───Test
        01_20190515_135255.ext
        02_20190515_135315.ext
        03_20190515_135317.ext
        04_20190515_135317.ext
```